# Determine if a directory is .gitignored with vc

Tags: vc, vc-mode

I would like to determine if the current directory/file is ignored by `.gitignore` with `vc`. In this case, only `git` matters, but of course a general solution would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid there is no such API in vc-mode or magit, but with little elisp you can implement all by yourself:

```
(defun my/is-git-ignored (file)
  (interactive "fFile:")
  (not (string-empty-p
        (shell-command-to-string (concat "git check-ignore " (shell-quote-argument file))))))
```